# How to access XMLHttpRequest within a Paw extension?

Tags: paw-app

I'm writing an extension to push our API back to our servers doc store - but it seems that XMLHttpRequest isn't available, perhaps because of the missing window object.

Is there an alternative within Paw?

Bonus question: What is Paw built on top, what do we / don't we have access to compared to the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual `XMLHttpRequest` isn't available in Paw, but instead we have `NetworkHTTPRequest` (doc [here](https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/Extensions/Reference/NetworkHTTPRequest)).

Here's an example:

```
var httpRequest = new NetworkHTTPRequest();  httpRequest.requestUrl = "http://httpbin.org/post";
httpRequest.requestMethod = "POST";
httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
httpRequest.requestBody = JSON.stringify({
    name: 'Paw'
})
httpRequest.send()

console.log('HTTP ' + httpRequest.responseStatusCode)
var response = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseBody)
console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
```

To answer the bonus part, Paw is a native Cocoa application written in Objective-C (a very few parts in C), but Extensions are using JavaScript Core which is also the engine that powers Safari on Mac and iOS. Though, it's plain JavaScript and doesn't exposes all methods that are available in web browsers. It also supports some ES6 features (see [Safari 9 on the ECMAScript 6 compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#safari9)).